# Каким способом разделить шаблон в DLE?

Tags: php, html, dle

Как разделить шаблон в DLE, чтобы при заходе в другие разделы загружался другой `tpl`?

Для галереи нашел решение:

```
if( $do == 'photo' ) $tpl->load_template ( 'main_photo.tpl' );
else $tpl->load_template ( 'main.tpl' );
```

Для статичных страниц не могу найти, точнее не помогает предыдущий прием.

```
if( $do == 'opisanie.html' ) $tpl->load_template ( 'main_photo.tpl' );
else $tpl->load_template ( 'main.tpl' );
```

Comment: Помогите решить вопрос пожалуйсто!

Answer (score 1):

в админке у статичных страниц можно указать свой tpl созданный. если ничего не указано, то по умолчанию он просто берет static.tpl, можно и его конечно поменять.

А если в зависимости от страницы, то можно покопаться в engine\modules\static.php, и добавить условие в код

```
        if( $view_template == "print" ) $tpl->load_template( 'static_print.tpl' );
        elseif( $static_result['tpl'] != '' ) $tpl->load_template( $static_result['tpl'] . '.tpl' );
        else $tpl->load_template( 'static.tpl' );
```

думаю тут все понятно

Comment: Не в этом дело...
Дело в том, что он подгружает, например, шаблон `static.tpl` в (поверх) `main.tpl`.

Comment: Я плохо разбираюсь в этом?
Можете показать код:

Если загружена страница `index.html`, то подгружать шаблон (`index.tpl`).
Если нет, то `main.tpl`.

или

Если загружена страница `feed.html`, то подргружать шаблон (`feed.tpl`).
Если нет, то `main.tpl`.

И куда его вставить?

Comment: тебе именно вместо main.tpl нужно что то вставить? Ну тогда так же как в твоем примере, только написать вместо $do == 'opisanie.html' 
$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == '/opisanie.html'

Comment: Тебе именно вместо main.tpl нужно вставить другое?

Проблема в том что в main.tpl слайдер на главное странице, мне нужно что бы подгружался main.tpl без слайдера.

То есть что бы заново стили со скриптами не прописывать...

Comment: Все равно не подгружает на страницу opisanie.html отдельный шаблон
Может как то хитро в админке нужно создать её(страницу)


if( $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == '/opisanie.html' ) $tpl->load_template ( 'main_photo2.tpl' );
else $tpl->load_template ( 'main.tpl' );